# How to deploy the wingsuit?

Tags: xbox-one, far-cry-4

In Far Cry 4, I have the wingsuit, but I don't know which button to press to deploy it. I'm playing this on Xbox One.

Comment: On PS4 you open your Wingsuit by pressing down your Left Stick. Maybe it's the same for the Xbox One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the **Left Stick**, clicking it down (L3). It took me a while to figure out how to operate the wing-suit as well. I found it's not really as simple as just pressing a button, most of the time.

To deploy the wing-suit, you must:

- Jump off a high place, like a cliff-side or building
- After falling for a short time, a prompt in the lower middle of your screen will appear, telling you to press **L3** to deploy the wing-suit
- After pressing the button, and after an agonizing delay, the wing-suit will deploy

Short story: don't deploy the wing-suit if you expect to hit the ground within a second or two. You will probably deploy your wing-suit, but immediately plant yourself firmly into the ground.

Comment: It's even worse on PC because deploying the wingsuit uses the same key as running. I can't count how many times I've run off a one-story building, accidentally deployed my wingsuit, and taken 3 or 4 bars of damage hitting the ground. :(